# How to position radiobutton under div?

Tags: php, html, css

I am newbie in HTML and CSS. I need radiobutton which locates under div. Now there's a div and radiobutton to right of.

```
<div class="rates">
        <? foreach ($rates as $rate) { ?>
            <div class="rates-block" <? if ($rate->id % 4 != 1) { ?> style="margin-left: 48px;" <? } ?>>
                <img src="/images/aukc_image/<?= $rate->img ?>" class="products-img rate-img" alt="product-1">
            </div>
            <input class="rate-radio" type="radio" name="radio1" value="<?= $rate->count ?>;<?= $rate->price ?>">
        <? } ?>
    </div>
```

There's my CSS for thats classes:

```
.rates {
    margin-top: 19px;
}
.rates-block {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 152px;
    height: 154px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);
    margin-left: 101px;
}
.rate-radio {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Now I have this[image]

But I need something like this

[image]

Comment: Have you tried placing the radio button within the save div as the image, and simply adding a `<br />` tag between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.rates {
    margin-top: 19px;
}

.product-wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 152px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    
}
.rates-block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 154px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);
}
.rate-radio {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="rates">
<div class="product-wrapper">
            <div class="rates-block">
                <img src="http://www.creativeprintpack.com/images/shoppingbag4.jpg" class="products-img rate-img" alt="product-1" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <input class="rate-radio" type="radio" name="radio1" value="wewe">Rate 0</input>
       </div>
                <div class="product-wrapper">
            <div class="rates-block">
                <img src="http://www.creativeprintpack.com/images/shoppingbag4.jpg" class="products-img rate-img" alt="product-1" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <input class="rate-radio" type="radio" name="radio1" value="wewe">Rate 1</input>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I have added a wrapper for each product/rate, which has the width set, the div containing the image is 100% width as the input aswell

Comment: Thanks! It's really helped me!